# C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(3717,9): error MSB3073: The command "msbuild "... exited with code 9009

Tags: c#

I'm working on a build server, and some of my projects have Post-Build Event to create a Web Deploy Package. Those Post-Build work perfectly on local Machine (be they command line build or VS2012 Build) but on the Jhenkin Server the comment fail with a 9009 Error, here is the command as run by the server (from it's log):

*C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(3717,9): error MSB3073: The command "msbuild "c:\Jenkins2\workspace\InstructorSystemFoundation-BuildAndCoverage\core\dev\src\Ownship\Host.Ui\Host.Ui.csproj" /target:Package /p:DeployOnBuild=false /p:PostBuildEvent= /p:SolutionDir=c:\Jenkins2\workspace\InstructorSystemFoundation-BuildAndCoverage\core\dev\solutions\Ownship\ /p:DeployIISAppPath="ISS Convergence/Cae.Iss.Ownship.Service.Host.Ui"" exited with code 9009.*

and here is the command from the PostBuild it self :
*msbuild "$(ProjectPath)" /target:Package /p:DeployOnBuild=false /p:PostBuildEvent= /p:SolutionDir=$(SolutionDir) /p:DeployIISAppPath="ISS Convergence/Cae.Iss.Ownship.Service.Host"*

I've seen several answer saying that error came up because of spaces in the path but as you can see there is none, so I'm kinda lost at this point

(PS : Sorry about my english, I'm not a native English Speaker)

Comment: Wait, you're using msbuild within the post-build-step?  That's... weird.  Really weird.  MSBuild is what consumes the proj file itself, so deployment stuff should be happening as part of the project's build settings and being defined on your MSbuild server, not stuffed into the post-build-step.


To meme it up, this is msbuildception.  Yo dawg I heard you like MSBuild so I put MSBuild in your MSBuild so you can build while you build.

Comment: I know it's weird but it's what I have to work with (we got a solution, with different project (read about 20), some of them web project that need to generate there web Deploy package at build)

I'm open to suggestion if you got a better way to do that (considering i can't change the server config at this point, can only change my own solution)